# Blender object does not have any modifiers in Python script

Tags: python, blender

I am writing a Python script for Blender 3.1 to set the "Line Art" modifier camera to the next camera in the scene to do a render.

The issue is my script cannot find any modifiers for my Stroke object:

```py
import bpy
import os

path_dir = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath

stroke = bpy.context.scene.objects.get('Stroke')

if not stroke:
    raise ValueError("Object with name Stroke not found")

if len(stroke.modifiers) == 0:
    raise ValueError("Stroke has no modifiers")
```

Error:

```
"render multiple cameras with line art.py", line 14, in <module>
ValueError: Stroke has no modifiers
```

It's definitely there:

[image]

I have tried

- forcing into object mode
- using the selected object instead of searching for it
- forcing the object to be selected

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Strokes (grease pencils) actually store their modifiers *their own way* for whatever reason.

Access them with `stroke.grease_pencil_modifiers`

Source: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.grease_pencil_modifiers